# vpc_idをサブネットリソースに渡す際のTerraformでの記載方法について

Tags: aws, terraform

#### 前提・実現したいこと

TerraformにてAWS環境上でVPCとSubnetの簡単な構成を作成したく思っております。
VPCで作成したvpc_idをSubnetに上手く渡せていないように見受けられるので
解決方法についてアドバイスなど提示いただけますと幸いです。

構成については、複数リソースを作成することを想定して
for_eachとlookupを利用して呼び出しを行っております。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
$ terraform plan -var-file=prd/resource-prd-vars.tfvars 
module.create_vpc_module.aws_vpc.vpc["vpc01"]: Refreshing state... [id=vpc-0419f19a0980c568f]

Error: Invalid index

  on ..\modules\vpc\vpc-main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_subnet" "subnet":
  15:   vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc[each.key].id
    |----------------
    | aws_vpc.vpc is object with 1 attribute "vpc01"
    | each.key is "subnet01"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

```
■ディレクトリ構成

└─VPC
    ├─modules
    │  └─vpc
    │          output.tf
    │          vpc-main.tf
    │          vpc-variavles.tf
    │
    └─resource
        │  backend.tf
        │  provider.tf
        │  resource-main.tf
        │  resource-variables.tf
        │  terraform.tfstate
        │  terraform.tfstate.backup
        └─prd
                resource-prd-vars.tfvars
```

■modules/vpc/vpc-main.tf

```
# ---------------------------------------------
# VPC
# ---------------------------------------------
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  for_each   = var.vpc
  cidr_block = lookup(each.value, "cidr_block", null)
  tags       = lookup(each.value, "tags", null)
}

# ---------------------------------------------
# Subnet
# ---------------------------------------------
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each                = var.subnet
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc[each.key].id
  availability_zone       = lookup(each.value, "availability_zone", null)
  cidr_block              = lookup(each.value, "cidr_block", null)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = lookup(each.value, "map_public_ip_on_launch", null)
  tags                    = lookup(each.value, "tags", null)
}
```

■modules/vpc/vpc-variables.tf

```
# ---------------------------------------------
# VPC作成時に利用する変数
# ---------------------------------------------

variable "vpc" {
  default = {}
}

# ---------------------------------------------
# subnet作成時に利用する変数
# ---------------------------------------------

variable "subnet" {
  default = {}
}
```

■resource/resource-main.tf

```
# ---------------------------------------------
# 各種モジュールの呼び出し
# ---------------------------------------------
module "create_vpc_module" {
  source = "../modules/vpc"
  vpc    = var.vpc
  subnet = var.subnet
}
```

■resource/resource-variables.tf

```
# ---------------------------------------------
# 変数の呼び出し
# ---------------------------------------------
variable "vpc" {}

variable "subnet" {}
```

■resource/prd/resource-prd-vars.tfvars

```
# vpc tfvars
# 実際の変数値を宣言する内容

# ---------------------------------------------
# VPC
# ---------------------------------------------

vpc = {
  vpc01 = {
    description = "テスト用vpc"
    cidr_block  = "10.0.0.0/16"
    tags = {
      "Name" : "prd-vpc",
      "Env" : "prd"
    }
  }
}

subnet = {
  subnet01 = {
    availability_zone       = "ap-northeast-1a"
    cidr_block              = "10.0.0.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
    tags = {
      "Name" : "subnet",
      "Env" : "prd"
    }
  }
}
```

#### 試したこと

outputを利用しmoduleに値を渡す、data形式で値を渡す、など
やってみましたが、正常に受け取れていないように見受けられます。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

terraform_version": "0.14.6"

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each                = var.subnet
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc[each.key].id
```

変数`subnet`のkeyは`subnet01`なので、`each.key`は`subnet01`を返します。

そのため、`vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc["subnet01"].id`となりますが、正しくは`vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc["vpc01"].id`です。

質問者さんの設計意図に沿っているかわかりませんが、.tfvarsを修正して、変数`vpc`と`subnet`のkeyを一致させれば、とりあえず動くはずです（動作確認はしていません）。

```
vpc = {
  01 = {
  ...
  }
}

subnet = {
  01 = {
  ...
  }
}
```